# MYSQL query only in set

Tags: mysql, sql, search, group-by

I have a table that links entries with associated tags with the following data in it:

```
entry_id |  tag_id
1        |  1
2        |  1
3        |  1
1        |  2
2        |  2
```

I am trying to write a query that returns only entries tagged with 1 AND 2, in this example entries 1 and 2 would be returned, while 3 would not, because it does not have both tags. The current query I am using works but I know can't be right:

```
SELECT entry_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tag_id ORDER BY tag_id)
FROM tags
GROUP BY entry_id
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tag_id ORDER BY tag_id) LIKE "%1,2%";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If (entry_id, tag_id) is unique:

```
SELECT entry_id
FROM yourtable
WHERE tag_id IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY entry_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

An alternative approach that doesn't require uniqueness and can also be faster:

```
SELECT T1.entry_id
FROM yourtable T1
JOIN yourtable T2
ON T1.entry_id = T2.entry_id
AND T1.tag_id = 1
WHERE T2.tag_id = 2
```

Comment: I like the first query you suggested, it's simple and perfect. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT entry_id
FROM tags t1 inner join tags t2 
on (t1.entry_id = t2.entry_id and t1.tag_id = 1 and t2.tag_id = 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good case for a self-join...

```
SELECT tagged1.entry_id
FROM tags tagged1
JOIN tags tagged2
    ON tagged1.entry_id = tagged2.entry_id
        AND tagged1.tag_id = 1
        AND tagged2.tag_id = 2;
```

Comment: This same answer has been posted before :)

Comment: You guys are always too fast for me! +1'd your answer.